# How to design REST API for export endpoint?

Tags: rest, export, api-design

I am designing a REST API and am running into a design issue. I have `alerts` that I'd like the user to be able to `export` to one of a handful of file formats. So we're already getting into actions/commands with `export`, which feels like RPC and not REST.

Moreover, I don't want to assume a default file format. Instead, I'd like to require it to be provided. I don't know how to design the API to do that, and I also don't know what response code to return if the required parameter isn't provided.

So here's my first crack at it:

`POST /api/alerts/export?format=csv`

OR

`POST /api/alerts/export/csv`

Is this endpoint set up the way you would? And is it set up in the right way to require the file format? And if the required file format isn't provided, what's the correct status code to return?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In fact you should consider HTTP content negotiation (or CONNEG) to do this. This leverages the `Accept` header (see the HTTP specification: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1) that specifies which is the expected media type for the response.

For example, for CSV, you could have something like that:

```
GET /api/alerts
Accept: text/csv
```

If you want to specify additional hints (file name, ...), the server could return the `Content-Disposition` header (see the HTTP specification: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) in the response, as described below:

```
GET /api/alerts
Accept: text/csv

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="alerts.csv" 

(...)
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Very interesting take. So the client would populate the request header with that info prior to sending it to the server?

Comment: Headers are part of the request itself in fact. See the specification for more details: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.

Comment: So using this design, how could I require that a file format be provided? Return a 400 bad request if an Accept header value isn't provided by the client?

Comment: You could but there is a dedicated status code for this: `406 Not Acceptable` ;-)

Comment: That said, the server could also provide a default format if nothing is specified within the request with an `Accept` header...