# How to distinguish two endpoints with same URL but different ACCEPT/content type in an Angular application?

Tags: angular, rest, export, endpoint

I am designing an Angular/SpringBoot webservice doing an export.

I followed this link [How to design REST API for export endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877541/how-to-design-rest-api-for-export-endpoint) to choose how to set my endpoint.

That endpoint has the same url than an existing one but produces different content (an excel export rather than a JSON).

So I have two endpoints:

- get /myapp/customers accept JSON
- get /myapp/customers accept XLS
  (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet)

How do I make Angular distinguish each of them?

Angular code:

```
  public export() {
        let filter = ...;
        return this.http.get(`/myapp/customers?${filter}`, { responseType: 'arraybuffer', headers: null,},)
            .subscribe(response => this.downLoadFile(response, 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'));
   }
   
   /**
  * Method is use to download file.
  * @param data - Array Buffer data
  * @param type - type of the document.
  */
  downLoadFile(data: any, type: string) {
    const fileName = 'customers.xlsx';
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
```

If I do as mentionned in the code above, it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding an `Accept` header, it solves the issue.

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
```

---

Whole code with the `headers` var parsed to the `http.get` method call:

```
public export() {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        let filter = ...;
        return this.http.get(`/myapp/customers?${filter}`, { responseType: 'arraybuffer', headers: headers,},)
            .subscribe(response => this.downLoadFile(response, 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'));
   }
   
   /**
  * Method is use to download file.
  * @param data - Array Buffer data
  * @param type - type of the document.
  */
  downLoadFile(data: any, type: string) {
    const fileName = 'customers.xlsx';
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    const blob = new Blob([data], { type });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
```